# How do we edit config files uploaded to zookeeper ensemble

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have uploaded solr config files to zookeeper and created collection indexed few documents into collection. Now I want to update schema file. Is it possible to edit the schema config file uploaded to zookeeper. ? If yes how do we do it. some source say upload updated schema config file to zookeeper which overwrites old one.

uploading updated config file is not tedious task But want to know if there is a way to edit the existing config file in zookeeper.

Thanks in advance,
vinod

Answer (score 1):

To update schema download latest configset associated with schema
Latest configset can be downloaded using following command:
solr zk -downconfig -d directory to download -n configset name -z ip:port of zookeeper

for example : solr zk -downconfig -d C:\solr\workingConfig -n configsetName -z localhost:2181

make required changes

Then Upload latest configset to zookeeper using following command.

solr zk -upconfig -d directory to upload -n configset name -z ip:port of zookeeper
For example: solr zk -upconfig -d C:\solr\workingConfig -n configsetName -z localhost:2181

Then you need to Reload schema so that changes can take effect immediately.

Schema can be reloaded using following command:
http://ip:port/solr/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=

Comment: As I mentioned, uploading updated config file is not tedious task But want to know if there is a way to edit the existing config file in zookeeper.